# Why do I keep getting this error when using Arrays.sort()?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

This is the code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.*;
public class MyClass {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int sum = 0;
    System.out.println("I will ask you to add 5 integers and I will add 5 to 
    each integer.\n");

    Scanner askInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter 5 integers:");

    int[] array = new int[5];
    array[0] = askInput.nextInt();
    array[1] = askInput.nextInt();
    array[2] = askInput.nextInt();
    array[3] = askInput.nextInt();
    array[4] = askInput.nextInt();

    System.out.println("\n");

    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        sum = array[i] + 5;
        System.out.println(sum);
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.sort(array[0]));



}
}
```

And this is my error:

/MyClass.java:26: error: no suitable method found for sort(int)
        System.out.println(Arrays.sort(array[0]));

and:

/MyClass.java:26: error: 'void' type not allowed here
        System.out.println(Arrays.sort(array));

This error is when I remove the [0] from "(array)".

Comment: please look how Arrays.sort works

Comment: What do you expect ``Arrays.sort(array[0])`` to do?

Comment: `Arrays.sort` sorts an array but doesn't return anything that could be printed. You need to use multiple lines of code to archieve what you are trying to do: Sort first and after that print the sorted array.

Comment: Please **read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`Arrays.sort(int[] a)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-int:A-). It takes an array as input, and it doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 2):

`'void' type not allowed here System.out.println(Arrays.sort(array));`

You can't print a `void` type.

You're receiving this error because `Arrays.sort(array)` sorts `array` *in place*; that is to say, it does **not** return a new array of sorted items, it directly modifies the contents of the array you pass as as the argument.

You can instead do the following:

```
//Arrays.toString() returns a string representation of an array so you can print it
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array)); 
//sort it
Arrays.sort(array);
//print the now sorted array
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

Documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int[])

Answer (score 0):

Also there is no need to import `java.util.Arrays` if you import `java.util.*`. This is because when you import `java.util.*` that automatically imports everything inside java.util, that would include java.util.Arrays, however to solve your problem you cannot print arrays directly. However, To convert an array to a String you can use `Arrays.toString(array)`. A good thing to note is that `Arrays.sort(array)` returns nothing and modifies the array directly, so you may want to clone your array beforehand, if you need the original for something else, to completely fix your code follow Strikegently's solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println(Arrays.sort(array[0]));
```

I think in the above line, you want to sort the array and then want to print the first value (at 0th index).

First, you need to understand that the return type of Arrays.sort() is void. Arrays.sort() method sort the values in the actual array.

You need to convert the above line in the following line.

```
Arrays.sort(array); // It sorts the array
System.out.println(array[0]); // It print the first value of the array
```